# How can I check if two elements in a vector are sequential by one?

Tags: c++, vector, sequence, poker

Say I have this

```
vector<int>SequentialByOne{1, 2, 3, 4, 5} //would like to search each element
//in the vector and if it is sequential a boolean value returns true


vector<int>notSequential{1, 6, 5, 8, 9} // This would return false


vector<int>notSequentialButOrdered{1, 3, 6, 9, 20} // This would return false


// So far I can get it to return true if the next number
// is bigger than the previous but can't figure out
// how to check that the next number is only one bigger.
```

This is for a poker hand elevator I was working on for a school project. I have a vector of 5 numbers that is ordered and now I need to search through that vector to find if they are in exact order +1.

This is what I had so far

```
sort(hand.begin(), hand.end()); // This is the vector name

int a;
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if(hand[i] < hand[i + 1] - 1)
            a++;
    }
}

bool has_straight
{
    if(a == 5)
        return true;
}
```

Comment: not really clear what is the problem. If you want to check for equality instead of inequality then just do it, ie `if (hand[i] = hand[i+1] + 1)` instead of `if(hand[i] < hand[i + 1] - 1)`

Comment: Check if `hand[i + 1] - hand[i] == 1`? Or rather, check if `hand[i + 1] - hand[i] != 1` and if true then return false.

Comment: What is wrong with your current code? If you'd like someone to review your code: look at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorting first is good; then checking is easy.  But don't forget to special-case 2-3-4-5-A.

Comment: How are you representing the rank of the card? Are your cards just numbers from 1..52, or 1..13 with suits separate? If the former, in what order? Without knowing this, there's no way to compare ranks.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have already sorted the `vector` you can just check (assuming no duplicates in the vector) if the difference between the first and last element is 4:

```
hand.back() - hand.front() == 4
```